# What big benefits come from VS2010 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The Visual Studio SP1 beta just became available. I'm tempted to give it a try, since it apparently contains quite a few fixes and improvements. I haven't had any specific issues with VS2010, so I'm not certain what I'd get out of it right now.

A query to those in the know: what specific improvements in SP1 will you be benefiting from?

Comment: Your title says "expect" but the actual question implies known benefits. Slightly ambiguous.

Comment: @DeadMG A good point, I've edited the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well

Unit Testing on .NET 3.5 (it was for .net 4.0 only)

Performance Wizard for Silverlight

& intellitrace for sharepoint projects is all i can remember now

Answer (score 1):

links to announcements/overview (CW so others can add)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioExplosionVS2010SP1BETAReleasedAndContext.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/12/07/announcing-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in SQL CE, there are several improvements enumerated by Scott Guthrie:

> VS 2010 SP1 includes much improved tooling support for SQL CE, and
>   adds support for using SQL CE within ASP.NET projects for the first
>   time.  With VS 2010 SP1 you can now:
>
> ```
> Create new SQL CE Databases
> Edit and Modify SQL CE Database Schema and Indexes
> Populate SQL CE Databases within Data
> Use the Entity Framework (EF) designer to create model layers against SQL CE databases
> Use EF Code First to define model layers in code, then create a SQL CE database from them, and optionally edit the DB with VS
> Deploy SQL CE databases to remote servers using Web Deploy and optionally convert them to full SQL Server databases
> ```
>
> You can take advantage of all of the above features from within both
>   ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC based projects.